# PHP can I place a global variable inside a variable sample: $names = $_FILES ["dfile"];

Tags: php, html, global-variables

Trying to build a admin panel for uploading text and images here is the html page. The Html page is working fine it's the php page that is broken the html is just here for reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<title>Administartor Panel</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Heritage House Administartor Panel</h1>
<br/>
<h2>
<a href="#eone">Event One</a>&nbsp;
<a href="#etwo">Event Two</a>&nbsp;
<a href="#ethree">Event Three</a>&nbsp;
<a href="#efour">Event Four</a>&nbsp;
<a href="#efive">Event Five</a>&nbsp;
<a href="#esix">Event Six</a>&nbsp;
</h2>
<br/>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="eone">
<br/>
<p>Event One</P>
<p> Please name the picture file1 before uploading.</p>
<form action="upload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="afile" id="afile" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<form action="WriteTxt1.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Input Text for artical One:</label>
<textarea rows="25" cols="100" name="content">
</textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="etwo">
<p >Event Two</P>
<p> Please name the picture file2 before uploading.</p>
<form action="upload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="bfile" id="bfile" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<form action="WriteTxt2.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Input Text for artical Two:</label>
<textarea rows="25" cols="100" name="content">
</textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="ethree" >
<p >Event Three</P>
<p> Please name the picture file3 before uploading.</p>
<form action="upload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="cfile" id="cfile" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<form action="WriteTxt3.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Input Text for artical Three:</label>
<textarea rows="25" cols="100" name="content">
</textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="efour" >
<p >Event Four</P>
<p> Please name the picture file4 before uploading.</p>
<form action="upload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="dfile" id="dfile" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<form action="WriteTxt4.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Input Text for artical Four:</label>
<textarea rows="25" cols="100" name="content">
</textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="efive" >
<p >Event Five</P>
<p> Please name the picture file5 before uploading.</p>
<form action="upload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="efile" id="efile" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<form action="WriteTxt5.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Input Text for artical Five:</label>
<textarea rows="25" cols="100" name="content">
</textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="esix" >
<p >Event Six</P>
<p> Please name the picture file6 before uploading.</p>
<form action="upload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="ffile" id="file6" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<form action="WriteTxt6.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Input Text for artical Six:</label>
<textarea rows="25" cols="100" name="content">
</textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

trying to rename the files uploaded based on which form they come from on the html page afile,bfile etc.
I have tried this php file a number of different ways. I can get it to work when I eliminate the large IF statement and make 6 separate files for uploading but I was hoping to make it one file 
This is what I believe makes it fail moving the global variables in to normal vars?

```
        <?php
    //This function separates the extension from the rest of the file name and returns it
    function findexts ($filename)
    {
    $filename = strtolower($filename) ;
    $exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename) ;
    $n = count($exts)-1;
    $exts = $exts[$n];
    return $exts;
    } 
    //This if statement assigns the new file name to a variable and displays a message.
    if (file_exists($_FILES["afile"]["tmp_name"]))
      {
      $new = "file1.";
      $type = $_FILES ["afile"] ["type"];
      $size = $_FILES ["afile"] ["size"];
      $error = $_FILES ["afile"] ["error"];
      $name = $_FILES ["afile"] ["name"];
      $tmpname = $_FILES["afile"]["tmp_name"];
      $names = "afile";
      echo "file1 Uploaded <br />";
      }
    elseif (file_exists($_FILES["bfile"]["tmp_name"]))
      {
      $new = "file2.";
      $type = $_FILES ["bfile"] ["type"];
      $size = $_FILES ["bfile"] ["size"];
      $error = $_FILES ["bfile"] ["error"];
      $name = $_FILES ["bfile"] ["name"];
      $tmpname = $_FILES["bfile"]["tmp_name"];
      $names = "bfile";
      echo "file2 Uploaded <br />";
      }
    elseif (file_exists($_FILES["cfile"]["tmp_name"]))
      {
      $new = "file3.";
      $type = $_FILES ["cfile"] ["type"];
      $size = $_FILES ["cfile"] ["size"];
      $error = $_FILES ["cfile"] ["error"];
      $name = $_FILES ["cfile"] ["name"];
      $tmpname = $_FILES["cfile"]["tmp_name"];
      $names = "cfile";
      echo "file3 Uploaded <br />";
      }
    elseif (file_exists($_FILES["dfile"]["tmp_name"]))
      {
      $new = "file4.";
      $type = $_FILES ["dfile"] ["type"];
      $size = $_FILES ["dfile"] ["size"];
      $error = $_FILES ["dfile"] ["error"];
      $name = $_FILES ["dfile"] ["name"];
      $tmpname = $_FILES["dfile"]["tmp_name"];
      $names = "dfile";
      echo "file4 Uploaded <br />";
      }
    elseif (file_exists($_FILES["efile"]["tmp_name"]))
      {
      $new = "file5.";
      $type = $_FILES ["efile"] ["type"];
      $size = $_FILES ["efile"] ["size"];
      $error = $_FILES ["efile"] ["error"];
      $name = $_FILES ["efile"] ["name"];
      $tmpname = $_FILES["efile"]["tmp_name"];
      $names = "efile";
      echo "file5 Uploaded <br />";
      }
    elseif (file_exists($_FILES["ffile"]["tmp_name"]))
      {
      $new = "file6.";
      $type = $_FILES ["ffile"] ["type"];
      $size = $_FILES ["ffile"] ["size"];
      $error = $_FILES ["ffile"] ["error"];
      $name = $_FILES ["ffile"] ["name"];
      $tmpname = $_FILES["ffile"]["tmp_name"];
      $names = "ffile";
      echo "file6 Uploaded <br />";
      }

    //This applies the function to our file
    $ext = findexts ($_FILES ['$names'] ['name']) ;
        //This assigns the subdirectory you want to save into.
        $targett = "forms/upload/";
        //This combines the directory, the new file name, and the extension
        $target = $targett . $new.$ext; 
        // makes sure image meets specs
    if ((($type == "image/gif")
    || ($type == "image/jpeg")
    || ($type == "image/pjpeg"))
    && ($size < 2000000))
      {
      if ( $error > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $error . "<br />";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Thank You! <br />";
        }
    //saves uploaded file
        if (file_exists("forms/upload/" . $name))
          {
          move_uploaded_file( $tmpname, $target);
          echo $name . " Old File Over Written. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file( $tmpname, $target);
          echo "Stored in: " . "forms/upload/" . $name;
          }   
?>
```

Maybe is my elseif statement broken?

I have only been playing with this php stuff for about a week so if I'm way off mark here sorry for wasting your time.

Maybe if I try making 6 functions with the globals  `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target);` than placeing them in the elseif statement it could work?

this is a copy of the working php page

```
<?php
//This function separates the extension from the rest of the file name and returns it
function findexts ($filename)
{
$filename = strtolower($filename) ;
$exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename) ;
$n = count($exts)-1;
$exts = $exts[$n];
return $exts;
} 
//This applies the function to our file
$ext = findexts ($_FILES['afile']['name']) ;
    //This line assigns a random number to a variable. You could also use a timestamp here if you prefer.
    $new = "file1.";
    //This assigns the subdirectory you want to save into... make sure it exists!
    $targett = "forms/upload/";
    //This combines the directory, the random file name, and the extension
    $target = $targett . $new.$ext; 
if ((($_FILES["afile"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["afile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["afile"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["afile"]["size"] < 2000000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["afile"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["afile"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["afile"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["afile"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["afile"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["afile"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("forms/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["afile"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["afile"]["tmp_name"], $target);
      echo "Stored in: " . "forms/upload/" . $_FILES["afile"]["name"];
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Invalid file";
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for figuring out the Markdown editor correctly on the first try, and posting a whole lot of information about your problem.

Answer (score 1):

That is a heck of a lot of repeated code! Do you really need 6 separate HTML forms? Why not have one form, with a dropdown for choosing the event?

```
<select name="event">
    <option value="afile">Event One</option>
    <option value="bfile">Event Two</option>
    ...etc
</select>
```

For the input, use:

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" id="file" />
```

Then instead of your lengthy if/else clauses, simply do something like this:

```
if ( isset($_POST['event']) && file_exists($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) )
{
    // base this code on the value of $_POST['event']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use

```
isset($_FILES["afile"])
```

instead of

```
file_exists($_FILES["afile"]["tmp_name"])
```

--edit

to answer your question in the title: it is possible, if, e.g $_FILES["afile"], is set. That way you'll have an array in your new variable.

Answer (score 0):

Very close to working actually.

```
//Uses $names as a key in $_FILES - no single quotes for variable expansion....
$ext = findexts($_FILES[$names]['name']);
```

Might I also suggest using some sort of loop instead of a big elseif with a bunch of pasted code.  Two improvements used: [foreach](http://php.net/foreach) on the $_FILES array, and [extract](http://php.net/extract)

```
foreach ($_FILES as $fileKey => $values)
{
  // Sets $type, $size, $name, $tmp_name, $error
  extract($values);
  //This applies the function to our file
  $ext = findexts($name) ;

  //This assigns the subdirectory you want to save into.
  $targett = "forms/upload/";
  //This combines the directory, the new file name, and the extension
  $target = $targett . $new.$ext; 
  // makes sure image meets specs
  if ((($type == "image/gif")
    || ($type == "image/jpeg")
    || ($type == "image/pjpeg"))
    && ($size < 2000000))
  {
    if ($error > 0)
    {
      echo "Return Code: " . $error . "<br />";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Thank You! <br />";
    }
    //saves uploaded file
    if (file_exists("forms/upload/" . $name))
    {
      move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name, $target);
      echo $name . " Old File Over Written. ";
    }
    else
    {
      move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name, $target);
      echo "Stored in: " . "forms/upload/" . $name;
    }         
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, missed that one :). It should be double quotes or no quotes at all.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to thank everyone who left answers to my questions I was quite amazed at the short response time to my question. After trying and testing your answers I was still coming up short of any type of real solution to my problem it wasn't till I discovered that I forgot to end a if statement that I started making progress towards a answer.

```
 if ((($type == "image/gif")
    || ($type == "image/jpeg")
    || ($type == "image/pjpeg"))
    && ($size < 2000000))
      {
```

Now that this if statement has a ending and I have had time to study all of your answers I'm sure I will have this page working to my liking in no time. 
It's working now but their are still refinements to be made. Here is my working html and php pages.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<!-- 
html admin page for HH 
-->
<title>Administartor Panel</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Heritage House Administartor Panel</h1>
<br/>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="eone">
<br/>
<p>Event Uploader</P>
<form action="formupload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="selection">Please select the event you would like to edit.</label>
<select name="selection">
<option value="file1">Event1</option>
<option value="file2">Event2</option>
<option value="file3">Event3</option>
<option value="file4">Event4</option>
<option value="file5">Event5</option>
<option value="file6">Event6</option>
</select>
<br />
<p> Please upload your event picture file here.</p>
<p align="center">
<label for="file">Photo:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</p>
</form>
<form action="WriteTxt1.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Input Text for the event artical:</label>
<textarea rows="25" cols="100" name="content">
</textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
</td>
</tr>

</form>
</td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
    //This function separates the extension from the rest of the file name and returns it
    function findexts ($filename)
    {
    $filename = strtolower($filename) ;
    $exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename) ;
    $n = count($exts)-1;
    $exts = $exts[$n];
    return $exts;
    } 
    //This if statement assigns the new file name to a variable from the value of the options menu in the html form selection.
 $new = $_POST ["selection"] . "."; 
    //This applies the function to our file
    $ext = findexts ($_FILES ["file"] ["name"]) ;
        //This assigns the subdirectory you want to save into.
        $targett = "forms/upload/";
        //This combines the directory, the new file name, and the extension
        $target = $targett . $new.$ext; 
        // makes sure image meets specs
    if ((($_FILES ["file"] ["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES ["file"] ["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES ["file"] ["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
    && ($_FILES ["file"] ["size"]< 2000000))
      {
      echo "file check pass<br />";
      }
      //makes an error if file does not meet standards 
      if ( $_FILES ["file"] ["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES ["file"] ["error"] . "<br />";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Thank You! <br />";
        }
    //saves uploaded file
        if (file_exists("forms/upload/" . $_FILES ["file"] ["name"]))
          {
          move_uploaded_file( $_FILES ["file"]["tmp_name"], $target);
          echo $_FILES ["file"] ["name"] . " Old File Over Written. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target);
          echo "Stored in: " . "forms/upload/" . $_FILES ["file"] ["name"];
          }   
?>
<html>
<!-- 
html to return user to admin page 
-->
<title>
Upload Result
</title>
<head>
<p>
<br />
Back To Admin Page
</p>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
<a href="adminarea.html">
<input type="button" value="Back" />
</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: I have only been using notepad2 and firefox to edit and error check my code. I'm guessing that their are better ways of debugging php out their right?